# Swift 3 - UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum memory issue

Tags: swift, memory, uiimagepickercontroller

I use the UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum method in my UIImagePickerController class to save photo taken with my app. It's working fine, but the problem is that it takes 30mb+ of RAM for each saved photos and the memory is never released, obviously it results in a crash due to memory issue if I save multiples photos.
Somebody can help me to resolve this please ?

Comment: that's the problem I don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

wrap the call in a autoreleasepool

`autoreleasepool {
    //do a single save here
}`

---

if memory doesnt go down 100% after that, check if you have something retaining the memory

Comment: It doesn't change anything. I can see in Instruments that it's "CG raster data" that takes this 30mb of memory each time. What can I do ?

Comment: The responsible caller is "CGDataProviderCreateWithCopyOfData"

Comment: are you maybe somehow keeping around a reference - how about showing us code